# Parse XML using regular expressions

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to parse some tags.

and the pattern is

```
<div id="tags">blah-blah<a href="http://url/tag">What_I_Want</a></div>
```

I thought it works

```
re.findall(">"."</a></div>")
```

but it wasn't

what's wrong with that?

------------ Update I -------------
now i know re is not good with html.

raj give me a answer

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '<div id="tags">blah-blah<a href="http://url/tag">What_I_Want</a></div>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.select('div > a:first')[0].text
'What_I_Want'
```

and i have another question.
how can i find

```
<div id blah blah </div>
```

in entire file?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sigh. Don't try to parse HTML using regex. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/104349

Comment: daniel-roseman : then how to search that words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to get the text of immediate child tag `a` of parent tag `div`.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '<div id="tags">blah-blah<a href="http://url/tag">What_I_Want</a></div>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.select('div > a:first')[0].text
'What_I_Want'
>>> soup.select('div > a')[0].text
'What_I_Want'
```

Comment: guy, really thanks, and i have a question about it. how can i search the <div id..../div> from entire html?

Comment: @EfirlusKim update your question.

Comment: @EfirlusKim if this a malformed html file? where is the closing `>` in the opening `div` tag?

Comment: there are so many <a ..... /a> and <div <a.../a></div>, the only different thing is id="tags" or not

Comment: @EfirlusKim accept an answer for this question and then ask a new question with exact input and output you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't

Different short answer: [Python XML parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (it even has examples)